# VSCode ServiceWorker/CacheStorage folder grows indefinitely large

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

VSCode is storing an awful lot of data in ~/Library/Application Support/Code/Service Worker/CacheStorage (on a Mac) -- 29.7GB in my case

Does anyone have the same problem as me, and how to solve this problem, I try to search the same problem on github, there are similar problems, but there is no solution

I try to search the same problem on github, there are similar problems, but there is no solution

Comment: "_there are similar problems_" links please :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the files in that cache they are related to WebViews.

A WebView renders HTML content and these folders are the caches of the browser tabs. Following an image link in a HTML file also creates a WebView.

They are not removed when you close the WebView.

- Close VSC.
- Delete all the folders in `Code/Service Worker/CacheStorage`
- Start VSC
- Open a WebView with images and JavaScript
- Ctrl click an image link in an HTML file (a WebView)
- close the WebView tabs
- close VSC

It will create new folders in `Code/Service Worker/CacheStorage` and they are not removed when VSC is closed or when the WebViews tabs are closed.

Solution to delete the content of `Code/Service Worker/CacheStorage` once a week when VSC is closed.

Or a bug/feature issue at the VSC repo.

Comment: if anyone creates a bug report, please ping me here with a link to it, or ping me in the issue ticket (@starball5)